# How do I find a Unison function by type?

Tags: unison-lang

Say I want to search for a function with a type like `[k] -> Set k`. I'm trying to use the `find` command from UCM, but that only lets me search by name. If I knew the name of the function I'm looking for, I wouldn't have to search for it

Is there something like Haskell's [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do `find : [k] -> Set k`. It's the colon (`:`) that tells UCM to do a search by type.

For example, in my codebase:

```
.> find : [t] -> Set t

  1.  base.data.Set.fromList : [k] -> Set k
```